# Outlook 2007 Mutliple Accounts

Tags: outlook, delegation

We have someone here set up with multiple accounts in Outlook 2007.  We don't have an exchange server.  When this person sends a meeting request from the non default account, it says it's from [non default email] on behalf of [default email].

My temporary (maybe permanent) solution is to have him switch his default account whenever he needs to send out a meeting request.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Do you have the following set? Choose Tools, Options, Calendar Options, and select the "When sending meeting requests over the Internet, use iCalendar format"

Answer (score 1):

The way we have solved this is to create another E-mail account under Account Settings.  When you do that, a drop down will appear under the Send button when creating a new email.  It will say Account.  Change the checkmark to the appropriate account.

Comment: Yeah, we have it set up that way, and it works fine for when he's sending e-mails.  When he sends a meeting request is when this problem occurs.